# Send parameters between promises

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Im doing a asynchronous process with node.js. using promises. My code is like this:

```
var net = require('net');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('MyBBDD.db');
var net = require('net');
var Q = require("q");

var firstFunction = function(v_user, v_mystring){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var mi;
    stmt = db.prepare("SELECT text1 FROM my_table WHERE user = ?");
    stmt.bind (v_user);
    stmt.get(function(error,row){
        if(!error && row){
                deferred.resolve({string: v_mystring, query: row.text1});
        }
            deferred.reject(new Error(error));
    });
    return deferred.promise;    
};

var secondFunction = function(result){
    console.log(result.string);
    console.log(result.query);
};

firstFunction('user000','Hello').then(secondFunction);
```

All in my code work fine but now, I want to concatenate in secondFunction my string received from firstFunction with other string for example "MyNewString".
Somebody know how can I solve it? Can I send "MyNewString" from my firstFunction to my secondFunction?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best to solve it will be resolve promise with object. Instead of returning just one value - result of querying DB you can return object that covers needed value.

#### With [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```js
function firstFunction(string) {
  return Promise.resolve({string: string, query: 'some result of query'})
}

function secondFunction(otherText, result) {
  console.log(result.query) // you have still access to result of query
  return result.string + otherText
};

firstFunction('foo').then(secondFunction.bind(null, 'bar')).then(console.log);
```

#### With closure

```js
function firstFunction(string) {
  return Promise.resolve({string: string, query: 'some result of query'})
}

function secondFunction(text) {
  return function(result) {
    return result.string + text
  }
};

firstFunction('foo').then(secondFunction('bar')).then(console.log);
```

#### With anonymous function expression

```js
function firstFunction(string) {
  return Promise.resolve({string: string, query: 'some result'})
}

function secondFunction(text, otherText) {
  return text.string + otherText
};

firstFunction('foo').then(function(result) {
  return secondFunction(result, 'bar')
}).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Krzysztof, thanks for reply me, Im new using node.js and I have a question about your code. Please, Can you write the example using all my code? Because if not I dont now how can I do that. Is it possible send my "otherText" when call to my firstFunction? For example:
firstFunction("otherText").then... after that do my sql query and send to secondFunction the result of my query and "otherText" and concatenate and print in secondFunction. Thanks!!

Comment: You need to resolve promise from `firstFunction` with object that covers two keys: passed text and result of query

Comment: Some edid have been made - I'm guessing that is something that you are looking for or it is enough close to it

Comment: Yes it's just what I wanted :), but I have other question because when you write 'some result' is the result of my query right? but when I use "return Promise.resolve", I can't use in "stmt.get(function(error,row){" because string will be 'undefined' and outside of  "stmt.get(function(error,row){" neither, because I can't access to my "row.text1". I don't know if I can explain myself...

Comment: You want probably something like `deferred.resolve({str: text, query: row.text1})`. After that in the *secondFunction* in result you are going to have access to object with those two properties

Comment: I update my code. Now in secondFunction, "otherText" is [object Object] and "result" is undefined. What changes I need to do in my code?

Comment: `secondFunction` takes only one argument - resolved value from `firstFunction`, `otherText` is object with two keys - **string** and **query**. Just `console.log(otherText.string)` to see the content of it.

Comment: Krysztof, now work fine! Thanks you very very very much, was so important for me. Have a nice day! :)